# Asymptotic expansion of the integral $\int_0^s \sqrt{\frac{1}{E-V(x)}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{E+x^2}}dx$ as $E\to0$ for $V(x)=-x^2+...$

Tags: asymptotics, mathematical-physics

How can one obtain an asymptotic expansion of an integral of the form
$$I(E)=\int_0^s \sqrt{\frac{1}{E-V(x)}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{E+x^2}}dx$$ as $E\to0^+$ given that $V(x)$ attains its maximum in $[0,s]$ at $x=0$ and that $V(x)$ is analytic around $x=0$ with a finite radius of convergence and that its Taylor expansion begins $V(x)=-x^2+...$.

It is clear that the first term is given by
$$I(E)\sim\int_0^s \sqrt{\frac{1}{-V(x)}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}}dx$$ I would like to be able to obtain an explicit expression for at least the next term.

Comment: I would first perform the change of integration variables from $x$ to $t$ via $x=E t$, factor out $1/\sqrt E$, and expand the integarand into a Maclaurin series about $x=0$.

Comment: Wouldn't the first term of the expansion of the integral diverge for the choice $V(x)=x^2+x^4$? I don't think one can answer this easily in any generality unless the form of the potential is restricted somehow.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg The OP has a constraint on $V(x)$, it must have a Taylor expansion about $x=0$ of the form $V(x)=-x^2+...$, your example does not satisfy this

Comment: Well I should have been more specific. $V(x)=-x^2-x^4$ is an example of a potential where the first term is finite but all the subleading terms in a series expansion in $E$ diverge, so it is impossible to expand it in a Taylor series, there must be non-analytic terms, like $\ln E$, for example.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I was not expecting it to necessarily be able to be expanded in a Taylor series, hence why I was asking for an asymptotic expansion. My issue is that I can't see how to apply any of the basic tricks for finding asymptotic expansions of integrals to tackle this problem

Comment: @J.L. This integral is too general to be tackled by a basic asymptotic trick because you are expanding around  a singular point, a maximum. As you take $E\to 0$ the time it takes for the classical particle to travel a set distance goes to infinity, so finding an asymptotic expansion for it is generally hard. Eliminating the leading behavior at the maximum generally doesn't fix the issue either, or I don't see a way to prove that for general $V(x)$.

Comment: @J.L. Your best bet for an standard asymptotic expansion may be performing a perturbative solution for $V(x)=-x^2+gf(x)~, g\to 0$, using the equation $x''=-V'(x)$, solving for the trajectory of the particle, and inverting to obtain the time required to get from $0\to s$. This should yield an expansion $t\sim \alpha \ln  E $ at any order in perturbation theory. This asymptotic expansion does get worse for $g$ large though.

Comment: I think I have finally found a rigorous argument for certain potentials $V(x)$, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be possible to provide a full answer for any potential $V(x)$, but we can outline an expansion that can provide a reasonable approximation to the integral under certain conditions. Consider the potential $V(x)=-x^2-gf(x)$, where $f$ is a continuous function in $(0,s]$ such that $f(x)=\mathcal{O}(x^\rho)$, with $\rho>2$ (at least in some neighborhood around the origin). We also demand that $V(x)$ is concave, with $V'(0)=0$. Then, one can find $I(0^+)$ for this class of potentials explicitly:

$$\lim_{E\to 0+}I(E)=\int_0^s\frac{dx}{x}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+g\frac{f(x)}{x^2}}}-1\right)$$

For as long as $g f(s)/s^2\ll 1$ the following asymptotic expansion should give reasonable approximations for the requisite integral:

$$I(E)\sim\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{g}{4}\right)^n{2n\choose n}\int_0^sdx\frac{(f(x))^n}{(E+x^2)^{n+1/2}}$$

By virtue of the assumptions, for any $n$, the integrals in the summand converge. The asymptotic expansion above may contain terms that are nonanalytic in $E$ as $E\to 0$, so this is probably as good a form as one can get with this general setup. For $f(x)=x^4$, for example, it can be shown that the asymptotic series contains terms of the form

$$I(E)\subset (\alpha_1E+\alpha_2 E^2+...)\log E$$

which cannot be obtained by expanding in powers of the energy. However, these terms are finite as $E\to 0^+$ and hence the leading divergence has been subtracted successfully.

**Note:** It is interesting to think about how the above series can fail for large $g$. The expansion of the following integral

$$\int_0^s\frac{dx}{\sqrt{E+gx^4}}=\frac{\Gamma^2(1/4)}{(gE)^{1/4}4\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{1}{g^{1/2}s}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{E}{4g s^4}\right)^n{2n \choose n}\frac{1}{4n+1}$$

is convergent, but it has a completely different dependence on the energy than the quadratic term and one could reason that for large $g$ the first series must fail at some point, since the expansion in inverse powers of the coupling $g$ has a finite radius of convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we have a (sum or) difference of square roots, we should always try the trick $\sqrt a-\sqrt b = \frac{a-b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}$ and see if it magically helps. Here
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{E-V(x)}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{E+x^2}} = \frac{\frac{1}{E-V(x)} -\frac{1}{E+x^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{E-V(x)}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{E+x^2}}} = \frac{V(x)+x^2}{(E-V(x))(E+x^2)\bigl( \sqrt{\frac{1}{E-V(x)}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{E+x^2}} \bigr)}.
$$
As $E\to0^+$, the denominator approaches $2x^3+\cdots$ and the numerator approaches $cx^3+\cdots$ for some $c\in\Bbb R$, leaving a much more tractable integral to approximate. (How to proceed from here depends on how good an approximation one needs, how much information we have about $V(x)$ and $s$, etc.)

Comment: Ideally there would be no restriction on s or V(x) other than those in the op. But if you have a suggestion for a restriction that would simplify the problem that might also be interesting